# Java: How to check if a Method from another .jar contains something?

Tags: java, methods, bukkit

I'm working on a bukkit plugin that checks plugins for force op methods. I know how to get the Methods of the plugins, but I don't know how to check if the Methods contain something like "player.setOp(true);" or something. Can you help me?

My code looks like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {

    RegisteredListener[] listeners = e.getHandlers().getRegisteredListeners();
    for(RegisteredListener lis : listeners) {
        for(Method m : lis.getListener().getClass().getMethods()) {
              //I don't know how to check if the methods contain something.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't really do that unless you do bytecode inspections...

Comment: ok, i believe this is too hard for me :D
I don't know what bytecode inspections are, but I don't think i'm able to use them :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot inspect such details by using Java Reflection.**

You will have to either look at the bytecode, or use some library that produces AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) and do investigation using the AST.